How to get user commits on github based on user logged in
Help, I am able to log users in via github and i am able to get the files from a github repo but when i try to display the commits of the logged in user, it shows i have no access token or access token incorrect.
Below I am handling log out correctly, fetch github user is also correct but i am having trouble with the access token:
I am trying to display the commits of a user in another file. I checked that they are logged in and that the repo is public and that commits have been made as well as prs. The code below shows how i am rendering the commits, i have another on for prs to show on the same page
  const renderCommits = () => {
    return userCommits.map(commit => (
      <div key={commit.sha}>
        <p>{commit.commit.message}</p>
        <p>{commit.commit.author.name} - {new Date(commit.commit.author.date).toLocaleString()}</p>
      </div>
    ));
  };

The code below here is that of the user context where everything seems to work except the final part, what am i missing?
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = () => {
    const clientID = process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID;
    const redirectUri = process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI;
    window.location.href = `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=${clientID}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('username');
    localStorage.removeItem('github_token');
    setUsername('');
    setAccessToken('');
    navigate('/');
  };

  const fetchGitHubUser = async (code) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/authenticate`, { code });
      setUsername(response.data.username);
      setAccessToken(response.data.access_token);
      localStorage.setItem('username', response.data.username);
      localStorage.setItem('github_token', response.data.access_token);
      navigate(`/profile/${response.data.username}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching GitHub user', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const code = urlParams.get('code');
    const storedUsername = localStorage.getItem('username');
    const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('github_token');

    if (code) {
      fetchGitHubUser(code);
    } else if (storedUsername && storedToken) {
      setUsername(storedUsername);
      setAccessToken(storedToken);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Username:', username);
    console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
  }, [username, accessToken]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ username, accessToken, handleLogin, handleLogout }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

